# Do I need an 'order' column in my sqlite table or is it safe to use rowid?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that relates a path to several nodes.  The order of the child nodes matters.

```
CREATE TABLE PathNodes ( pathId INTEGER, nodeId INTEGER )

rowid | pathId | nodeId
------+--------+-------
1     | 10     | 101
2     | 10     | 102
3     | 11     | 103
4     | 11     | 201
5     | 11     | 202
```

- I am only inserting the data once, after that it does not change.
- I insert the data in the correct order.
- I never delete any rows.
- I run a `VACUUM` once after inserting all data

If I want to get the nodes of a path in the correct order is it safe enough to just order by the rowid?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PathNodes
WHERE pathId = 2952178
ORDER BY rowId
```

Or will I need to add an explicit `nodeOrder` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, the rowid is [equivalent to an integer primary key](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

> In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the
>   ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
>   integer.

In your application, it makes sense for the database to prevent reuse of row id numbers. [SQLite might reuse rowids](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) the way you're using it right now.

> If you ever delete rows . . . then ROWIDs from previously deleted rows
>   might be reused when creating new rows . . . .

Since `integer primary key` is just an alias for rowid, and since `autoincrement` [prevents the reuse of rowids](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) from deleted rows, there's no space or performance penalty in declaring a new column as `integer primary key autoincrement`. And there are obvious advantages.

Create a new column as `integer primary key autoincrement`.

---

Since SQLite doesn't support directly adding a column declared `primary key`, you need to

- create a new table,
- copy the data into it in the right order,
- drop the old table, and
- rename the new table.

  ```
  sqlite> create table new (
     ...> node_order integer primary key autoincrement,
     ...> pathId integer not null,
     ...> nodeId integer not null
     ...> );
  sqlite> insert into new
     ...> (pathId, nodeId)
     ...> select pathId, nodeId 
     ...> from PathNodes
     ...> order by rowid;
  ```

Check the new data. Make sure it's exactly what you want. Then drop the old table, and rename the new table.

```
sqlite> drop table PathNodes;
sqlite> alter table new rename to PathNodes;
```

Comment: With AUTOINCREMENT, SQLite uses a separate counter in the [sqlite_sequence table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab), so it becomes slower. As long as the `rowid` is not referenced by other tables, reusing values from deleted rows is harmless.

Comment: *"reusing values from deleted rows is harmless"* Not in the OP's application.

Comment: "I never delete any rows", and the `rowid` is not referenced.

Comment: OP does `ORDER BY rowId`. His question is, "If I want to get the nodes of a path in the correct order is it safe enough to just order by the rowid?". That's not safe if SQLite is allowed to reuse rowids.